# How to customize the spring-data Repository method names?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a bunch of entities that use an underscore prefix before the field names and otherwise use camelcase.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long _id;


  private String _firstName;
  private String _lastName;

  @OneToOne
  private Foo _foo;

  // … methods omitted
}
```

The repository

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {

    Iterable<Customer> findByFoo(Foo foo);
}
```

The corresponding fields in the tables also use this naming scheme:

```
Customer: _id, _firstName, _lastName, _foo__id
```

Now that I am migrating this project to spring-data, I'm getting many IllegalArgumentExceptions with :

```
Could not create query metamodel for method
public abstract java.lang.Iterable  

com.example.repository.CustomerRepository.findByFoo(com.example.model.Foo)!

 Unable to locate Attribute  with the given name [foo] on this ManagedType [com.example.model.Customer]
```

I have no need to change hibernate's naming strategy, **but how can I change the query method generation naming algorithm** to map "findByFoo" -> "_foo" on the entity, or in JPQL terms "where x._foo__id = ?1"

I'm using old school xml configuration, and no spring boot.

---

**Edit: found this [in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), which isn't helpful..**

> "As we treat underscore as a reserved character we strongly advise to
>   follow standard Java naming conventions (i.e. not using underscores in
>   property names but camel case instead)."

Perhaps I should refactor the field names, drop the underscore, and then implement a hibernate naming strategy that adds the underscore back in?

Comment: there isn't an attribute called "foo". It has an underscore preceding it and your Spring method has none of that ...

Comment: Exactly. Hence the question. I want to know how to map "findByFoo" -> "_foo" on the entity.

Comment: If you have the underscore only because the column names have it, then you can remove it from the Java field and use the @Column annotation to specify a custom column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just repeat what's in the docs (although I'd be interested in the "isn't helpful" part). Use standard Java conventions for your Java code. Use the store specific means to customize the way properties are mapped onto database tables. JPA provides `@Column` annotations for that.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the advice. I ended up refactoring my field names and using a naming strategy to avoid having to add column annotations. Thanks for your work on spring data :)